# Pass interface to class constructor

Tags: c#

The language I use is C#.

I would like to ask a question of architectural nature.

Say we have classA:

```
public class classA
{
   public IParameters Parameters {get; set;}

   public classA(IParameters parameters)
   {
       Parameters = parameters;
   }

   // here goes the methods of the class

}
```

the interface IParamaters is the following:

```
public Interface IParameters
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
    public DateTime CreatedOn {get; set;}
    public TypeA A {get; set;}
    public TypeB B {get; set;}
}
```

Suppose that we want to instantiate an object of type ClassA. Then we should pass to it's constructor an object, which implements the interface IParameters.

Due to the fact, that we can't instantiate an interface, in other words to write 
IParameters parameters = new {....}; We should define a class that implements this interface. Since this interface has no methods and it has only properties all the classes that implement only this interface and they don't include any functionality would be a copy of all these properties.

Let classB implements IParameters:

```
public class classB : IParameters
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
    public DateTime CreatedOn {get; set;}
    public TypeA A {get; set;}
    public TypeB B {get; set;}
}
```

Then If we want to instantiate an object of type classA we should first instantiate an object of classB, like it follows:

```
classB b = new classB(){ .... };
classA a = new classA(b);
```

The reason why I have thinked the above is the fact tha inside another class I must create an object of classA. Unfortunately the classA has a big amount of code that it should be refactored. Some of types it uses, it should create them by the values it takes from its constructor, which has too many arguments. So one of the things, the came accross my mind, was to take all these parameters of the class outside of it. Then I though it would be better to pass to it's conructor a type that implements a specific interface rather than a concrete type, since it may change in the future.

I would like to know if the above apporach is worthy or not.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking, but I can't personally see anything wrong with the current architecture. This isn't all that uncommon. It further yields itself to an IoC library.

Comment: I think your proposed changes seem fine.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic. It suits in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud What do you mean by the "current architecture"? It sounds to me like the current architecture has a load of parameters passed in to the constructor, which are then used to create a variety of other classes.

Comment: @MatthewWatson, I think what I'm saying is that receiving an instance of an interface into the constructor seems fine to me. But again, it's *terribly unclear* what's being asked and even at that what exists now, so I'm just stating there's nothing inherently wrong with doing that.

Comment: @Michael my question in a few word is the following. Does the above approach is good or not. Do I have duplicate code, since my interface is the same as my class, or not. Sorry for not being clear. If I am not again, please let me know.

Comment: @ChristosPaisios, so does the `IParameter` interface *replace a large set of parameters that exist now?*

Comment: @Michael Exactly, as you wrote, it replaces a large parameters that exist now and may to the future change including more or deleting some of them.

Comment: @ChristosPaisios, because you have control over the object (i.e. you're able to change the constructor), it is my opinion that you refactor it and build constructor overloads that satisfy those parameters with defaults if possible. Otherwise, you'll probably need to continue down this path, but building the interface here doesn't really solve anything; it just puts the values into an object instead of being injected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you implement `dependency injection`, pattern of `SOLID.`

link : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)

This concept help you to define your `unit test easily`, and so create stub or mock on interface.

For future you can also define `container Unity` in order to initialize theses objects.

good for me